# Using Xamarin Forms with Telerik Controls

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, telerik, command

I have added a slide view to a .xaml page using the examples on their website, but the examples are quite small.

I have added a button to one of the views and my problem is that I am unable to correctly detect the button press event.

If I have the following in my .xaml page:

> < Button Text="Test" Clicked="ButtonTest" />

This works fine and I can detect the click event, but the problem is that I am using a MVVM framework and therefore I need the click event to be in my ViewModel and not the code behind.

Outside of this control, I would do the following:

> < Button Text="Test" Command="{Binding ButtonTest}" />

This fires the command correctly in my ViewModel.  I have tried this using other Telerik controls such as their ListView and the commands all work correctly from my ViewModel.

For some reason commands do not seem to work at all (whether ViewModel or code behind) when used in the SlideView.

Does anyone know why commands do not seem to work with the telerik SlideView and does anyone have any ideas of how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Could you show me your code?